# While dentro de While (While principal pára)

Tags: java, loop

Preciso criar 2 laços indo de 1 a 10, só que um dentro de outro.

FUNCIONA

- Usando for e for.
- Usando while e for.

Por que não funciona?

1) WHILE E WHILE

```
int a=1, b=1;

    while(a<=10) {          
        while(b<=10) {
            System.out.print(a + "-" + b + "  ");
            b++;
        } //fim while b
        System.out.println("");
        a++;
    }//fim while a
```

---

2) FOR E WHILE

```
int b=1;

    for(int a=1; a<=10; a++) {
        while(b<=10) {
            System.out.print(a + "-" + b + "  ");
            b++;                
        }// fim while b
    }// fim for a
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

O seu `while` -> `while` está funcionando. Ele está correto.

O problema é que a condição do segundo *while* `(b<=10)` sempre será falsa após o primeiro *loop*, isso porque você está somando `1` à variável `b` e não está *resetando* seu valor, por exemplo:

```
public class HelloWorld
{
  public static void main(String[] args)
  {
    int a=1, b=1;

    while(a<=10) {          
        while(b<=10) {
            System.out.print(a + "-" + b + "  ");
            b++;
        }
        System.out.println("");
        a++;
        b = 1; //Reseta o valor de "B"
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Fazendo um complemento à sua resposta:
Nos loops FOR, toda vez que você itera novamente pelo loop, a variável é inicializada novamente. O que ocorre é que há uma nova declaração de variável em cada iteração do loop, e por isso seu valor é sempre atualizado (i++ utiliza i no valor atual e adiciona +1 à próxima declaração) Por isso em sua declaração normalmente se vê for (**int i = 0**; i < x; i++).

Answer (score 3):

Só para te ensinar o jeito mais simples e lógico:

```
public class Contador {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        int a = 1;
        while ( a < 11) {
            int b = 1;
            while (b < 11) System.out.printf("%02d - %02d, ", a, b++);
            System.out.println();
            a++;
        }
    }
}
```

Veja [funcionando no **ideone**](https://ideone.com/qD0prY). E [no **repl.it**](https://repl.it/join/trfripwk-maniero). Também [coloquei no **GitHub** para referência futura](https://github.com/maniero/SOpt/blob/master/Java/Algorithm/Loop.java).